# Create directory with JS

Tags: javascript, activexobject, filesystemobject

How to create folders with JS:

```
    var sFolderPath = 'images';
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    if (!fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath)) {
        fso.CreateFolder(retVal);
        return;
        }
```

I got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined`

i know that "ActiveXObject" work only on IE, so i need other solution that work on all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Only Internet Explorer supports `ActiveXObject`. If you are trying this in another browser, it won't be supported.